# Field of fractions of a local ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers

Consider the following local ring:

$\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}=\{\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}: gcd(a,b)=1 \land   2\nmid b \}$.

Describe is **its** field of fractions.

I guess this field of fractions is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself because for example $\frac{\frac{6}{11}}{\frac{8}{13}}=\frac{39}{44}$.

I don have any clue where to start. Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand all the definitions? In particular, do you know what a field of fractions is?

Comment: I guess i do, but my experience is working with the typical field of fractions of Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, so by the universal property of fields of fractions, there is a ring homomorphism $Quot(\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$. However, any ring homomorphism between fields must be injective, so $Quot(\mathbb{Z}_{(2)})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$. As $\mathbb{Q}$ is a prime field, the only subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.

Therefore, $Quot(\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}) = \mathbb{Q}$